# WatchKit XCODE 6.3 ISSUE

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a problem with WatchKit in XCODE 6.3 i can't build my app.
Xcode tell me

> error: WatchKit apps must have a deployment target equal to iOS 8.2 (was 8.3).

Do someone knows something about this issue ?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WatchKit apps must have a deployment target equal to iOS 8.2 (was 8.3)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242067/watchkit-apps-must-have-a-deployment-target-equal-to-ios-8-2-was-8-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iOS app can target versions less that 8.2, but the WatchKit app and WatchKit extension must target iOS 8.2 (or later I'm assuming). Please make sure you're satisfying those requirements.

See [this Apple Developer Forums link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1117950#1117950) for more info.

Comment: Yes everything all right now i have another issue "error: The value of CFBundleShortVersionString in your WatchKit app's Info.plist (1.0) does not match the value in your companion app's Info.plist (1.2.4). These values are required to match."

Comment: thanks everything fine right know :) sometimes XCODE it's really strange

Comment: @BenKane I still not able to fix this issue. CFBundleShortVersionString means what?

Comment: @iOSdev That's the property list key for the version number. You'll see it in your app's plist as `Bundle versions string, short`. You can also set it above the build number on the app settings page. You could always search your project (cmd + shift + f) for `CFBundleShortVersionString` to see where it is used :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. It was actually a bug in Xcode 6.3. For some reason Xcode wanted deployment target of WatchKit App (and Not our app target) to be exactly 8.2

Changing "iOS Deployment Target" field in build settings of Watchkit app target to 8.2 as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29242067/1495678) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it to be a bug of Xcode 6.3, it generally appears if we add a target for watch app in a project which have previously deployment target less than 8.2 . To resolve the issue, you can change your deployment target for all the individual targets of your project (watch kit extension and iOS app) as 8.2, clean the project, restart the Xcode, hope your problem will be resolved.