# error: WatchKit apps must have a deployment target equal to iOS 8.2 (was 8.3)

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I just updated my project from 8.2. to 8.3 (using the latest xCode Version 6.3 6D570).
Now i get this error

> error: WatchKit apps must have a deployment target equal to iOS 8.2
>   (was 8.3).

The project and all targets are set to **Latest SDK 8.3**

What did I miss?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WatchKit apps must have a deployment target equal to iOS 8.2 (was 8.3)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242067/watchkit-apps-must-have-a-deployment-target-equal-to-ios-8-2-was-8-3)

Answer (score 14):

I resolved this by:

1. Right-clicking my PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj file and choosing "Show Package Contents".
2. Opening project.pbxproj in a text editor.
3. Changing all instances of "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.3;" to "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.2;"

After this change my project compiled and ran fine.

Comment: Really Superb Works...Good & helpful Solution posted by @Jastin. Thanks a Lots once again.

Answer (score 1):

Build successful.
I just changed the **iOS Deployment Target** of the Watch App Target to 8.2.

Why is that?

Comment: I've seen some strange behavior when upgrading an Xcode 6.2 project to 6.3. Probably what you did "reset" some bad state in the Xcode project file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , just select watch app -> go to build settings ->search for watchOS Deployment Target-> select lower version there based on the one of the watch you're using.