# Add Apple Watch to iOS app that has deployment target IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

When I try to add Apple Watch to my project that support IOS 7+, I get an error that in order to add Apple Watch deployment target should be minimum 8.2 When I checked instagram, it provides Apple Watch support and they support IOS 7 also. How can I add Apple Watch and at the same time run app on  IOS 7 devices also.

[image: Instagram]

[image: Instagram description. It says 7.0 or later]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution to the problem. It was actually a bug in Xcode 6.3. For some reason Xcode wanted deployment target of WatchKit App (and Not **our app target**) to be exactly 8.2

Changing "iOS Deployment Target" field in build settings of Watchkit app target to 8.2 [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29242067/1495678) solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your deployment target can be iOS 7.0, but you'll have to build your app using the iOS 8.2 SDK or higher.

Comment: My deployment target is 7.2 and base sdk is selected  as Default(ios 8.3). Still getting error.

Comment: Solved. It was actually a bug in Xcode 6.3. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29242067/1495678

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused between `Deployment Target` and `Build SDK`.

You can select the `Deployment Target` to **iOS7 +**

And you can also Build it using **iOS 8.2 SDK**

Just select the `Deployment Target` like this :

[image: Deployment target for Apple Watch]

And the `Architecture` to *iOS 8.2 or 8.3*

[image: Build SDK for Apple Watch]

**You should have some deprecated warnings.**

Answer (score 1):

deployment target must be 8.2 for the apple watch app target and apple watch extention.

And make sure that the Valid Architectures have arm64 for all watch target.

[image]