# WatchKit extension of 7.1 compatible target: WKInterfaceLabel

Tags: ios, watchkit, ios7.1, wkinterfacelabel

I am trying to add a WatchKit target to an app still supporting iOS 7.1. I supposed the app and Watchkit versions could use different versions. Yet when I add:

```
@IBOutlet var bus: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet var location: WKInterfaceLabel!
```

The compiler signals error:

> 'WKInterfaceLabel' is only available on iOS 8.2 or newer.

Does it need I need to drop the support of iOS 7 if I want to extend the app to the Watch, or is there a way out?

Comment: Did you set the deployment target of your watch app/extension to 8.2?

Comment: You need change iOS Deployment Target of WatchApp and WatchKit Extension on iOS 8.2
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29865947/1155354

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did not note that option at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, there is a specific iOS deployment target in the deployment section of the Watchkit and Watchkit extension.