# Can't compile iOS project with Watch App on XCode 11.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos

After updating XCode to its latest version, I can't compile my project with a companion watch app .

The error it presents is the following:

> error: The deployment targets of your WatchKit app (2.0) and WatchKit
>   extension (8.2) must be equal.

I'v removed the watch app and it compiled, but is brought back to that issue after adding the app back (as a new watch app, not by rolling back the changes)

I'v also found a similar issue from 2015... but the solution is not working this time:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242067/watchkit-apps-must-have-a-deployment-target-equal-to-ios-8-2-was-8-3)

Also... My targets are on iOS 9.0 and WatchOS 2.0, although it doesn't work even if I change them to the latest versions of the OSs

Comment: Check your WatchKit app and WatchKit extension targets. It isn't complaining about your iOS app but your two watch components.

Comment: yeah... they are all set as I described... Moreover... there is no reference to 8.2 anywhere on the project / code